# What type of test do I use in G Power?

Tags: anova, t-test, manova, gpower

I've got 1 IV with 2 levels (within-subjects) and 4 VD's (with 7 levels).
What type of test do I use in this case ?

Thank you

Comment: Greg, welcome to Cross Validated. We know lots of acronyms here.  IV is independent variable, OK. VD is . . . well perhaps that is worth clarifying. How about "Variable Dependiente"? Also, is "G-Power" the branded open source product, or something else?  (In the context of VD, I can think of other interpretations of G-Power.) In general, please feel free to be specific and clear and detailed when writing questions here.

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply, I meant DV for dependent variable and yes G-Power is the program to calculate statistical power.